# How to force Poetry to reinstall a Git dependency from a branch

Tags: python-poetry

I have a Poetry dependency pinned down as the following in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
top-framework = { git = "https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/top-framework.git", rev = "master" }
```

Even if I push new commits to `master` branch on Github, `poetry install` won't reinstall the changes.

Comment: What woroks for me is this: `poetry update top-framework`

Comment: This might be correct. Thank you @Engensmax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [an ongoing issue with Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3958). Unfortunately, at the moment Poetry does not pick up changes inside Git branches.

However you can force reinstall the package with `pip` after activating `poetry shell`. The force reinstall will always pick the latest changes from Git:

```bash
pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps "git+https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/top-framework.git#master"
```

Comment: What surprises me is that even when I remove the package with `pip uninstall` and then run `poetry install --no-cache`, it won't pull the most recent commit. The culprit there is that the commit hash is stored in the lock file. Not sure how to update that without updating all references....

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of poetry - I am on 1.7 now - `poetry update [--no-cache]` does the trick. To ensure that poetry does not try to update all the packages, pass the package name as an argument to poetry update.

If this is your pyproject.toml

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pydantic = "^2.1"
isodate = "^0.6.1"
pandas = "^2.1.4"
pysheds = {git = "https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds.git", branch = "development"}
```

just run the following command to get the latest commit to the *development* branch:

```bash
poetry update pysheds --no-cache
```